# Not catching on change event on checkboxs using jquery on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of questions that is getting loaded from a database when the page loads.  I am parsing the list of questions, and added a checkbox to each question.  I am planning on adding the id of each check box to an array which I am going to then pass back to the database for further processing.

```
$.each(data.d.crit1,function(key,value){
    var rowId = 'QID_0'+value.CLASS_QUESTION_ID;
    var codes = value.CODES ? value.CODES : '';
    $("#tblCrit1").append("<tr class='row' id='"+rowId+"'></tr>");
    $("#"+rowId).addClass('critical1').css('cursor','pointer')
        .append("<td class='chckbox'><input type='checkbox' id='cbx_Q"+value.CLASS_QUESTION_ID+"'/></td>")
        .append("<td>"+value.QUESTION_TEXT+"</td>")
        .append("<td>"+codes+"</td>");
});
```

I am attempting to attach an on change event handler to the check boxes, but for some reason, I cannot get the event to fire.

I've tried a few different methods that I thought should have worked.  Something like:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change',function(){...});
```

and a few other permutations with no luck.

I'm apparently doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you attach the onchange handler inside your document.onReady()?

Comment: yes.  I omitted that portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the selector `$("input[type=checkbox]")` to `$("input[type='checkbox']")`

**EDIT**: You should have ssomething like this:

```
$('#tblCrit1').on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function(){...});
```

Attach the handler after loading the data.

Comment: your edit did the trick.  I tried attaching it to the table, but i couldn't get it to fire for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly without seeing context for the two excerpts, but I expect

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change',function(){...});
```

May be being run before the method which adds the checkbox to the page. The `on` function will only be bound to elements that are on the page at the time it is run.

I would suggest either using

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {...});
```

Which will attach the listener to `document` and any change events that bubble up and match the selector will trigger the callback.

Or attach the event listener to the input in the method that creates it, I think this would be neater.